# no sound when turning key, but battery should be fine

Tags: battery, nissan, ignition, starter, wiring

I know it isn't the battery. I just had the charge checked, and it starts... Sometimes. But the majority of the time, I turn the key and there's no noise under the hood. The door indicator beeps when I put the key in and leave the door open, but the headlights won't work and the electric locks don't work either. I see some dashboard lights without the key in. I know the car has *some* electricity.

When the car does start, it isn't great. It sounds like the connection is weak, the electronics flicker a little. But it sounds like the second it gets any stress on it it will shut off. I haven't been able to get it back on to actually test that.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You mentioned you had the battery charge checked, what is the battery voltage?  How old is the battery?  It sounds like it might be a weak battery or a bad connection either battery cables to the battery terminals or to ground (engine or body).

Comment: @MikeH I don't know the voltage. I'd just took it to an AutoZone to get checked and recharged. When I not it back they told me it was at "about 85% charge". And it worked before I took the battery out (I took it out to get checked because there was a lot of corrosion built up on one post and I was worried it was damaged). After getting it back, it no longer works. I even tried starting with a jump from a good battery, but it acted the exact same.

Comment: Your question seems to contradict itself, for example -“ When the car does start, it isn't great. It sounds like the connection is weak, the electronics flicker a little. But it sounds like the second it gets any stress on it it will shut off. I haven't been able to get it back on to actually test that.”. Does the car start sometimes, or not?

Comment: @HandyHowie I got it to start twice after I put it back in and there was no sound. Both times were after I'd tried, taken the battery out, scrubbed rust and corrosion from the contacts, and then put it back. But it was not consistent and no longer works. Both times it did start it was like I described; like the electricity was flickering in the vehicle.

Comment: As a next step I would suggest having your battery ground connection tested.  You can do this if you have or could borrow a multi-meter.   If not, take it to your local auto repair shop.  It is a quick and easy test to perform.